# What is "spell power"?

Tags: nine-parchments

Many skills in Nine Parchments give bonuses to "spell power". What is this bonus, and does it apply to healing as well as damage-dealing spells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answered by the developer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/471550/discussions/0/1692659769960314578/#c1692659769962075379):

> We use the term Spell Power instead of Spell Damage because most our boosts affect all types of spells, meaning they affect both the spells' damage and healing power (and in the case of Life vs Death, the effect of your Life spell on that Death element :) )